# read function names from deploy.config in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell.
I have a powershell script, which is having few functions.
ex: one of the functions is

```
Function Createconfigfile() 
{
.
.
.
}
Createconfigfile
```

My requirement is, i want to read the function name(Createconfigfile) from deploy.config file. If the function name(both in powershell scritpt and deploy.config) matches, it will execute the function, otherwise it will skip and move on to the next step.

Here is my sample deploy.config file,

```
<configuration>
</user>
<site id="Texas" issecure="true">
    <functionname>Createconfigfile</functionname>
    </site>
</configuration>
```

Can someone please help me on this..
Thank you so much...

Comment: Could you just call every <functionname> listed in deploy.config? Any that do not exist in the powershell script will error (not run).

Comment: Actually my real script has 3 functions but i want to read only one function from deploy.config.
if I run .ps1 it will read function name from deploy.config
and match the function name with .ps1 file, if same..it will execute...otherwise will skip. and move to next step. Evrything should be written in .ps1 file

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little demo of how this can be done. Had to add a start user tag to make the config file valid xml.

```
Function Createconfigfile() 
{
    echo "Good stuff"
}


$xml = @"
<configuration>
<user></user>
<site id="Texas" issecure="true">
    <functionname>Createconfigfile</functionname>
    </site>
</configuration>
"@
$filename = ".\Configfile.xml"
$xml  | Set-Content $filename

[xml]$config = Get-Content $filename

if (Test-Path ("function:\{0}" -f $config.configuration.site.functionname))
{
    echo "calling function"
    & ($config.configuration.site.functionname)
}
# Call other functions here
function2
function3
```